# Como puedo proteger la rama master de mi repositorio en AWS CodeCommit

Tags: json, git, aws, users-roles, repositorio

Tenemos un proyecto alojado en un repositorio de code commit en AWS, el proyecto tiene varias ramas de diferentes programadores.

Para trabajar primero mandamos PR's a la rama dev y esto genera un PR automatico a la rama master (Recalcar que tenemos reglas de aprobación).

El problema es que varios se equivocan y mandan el PR directo a master y nos genera un desorden en cuanto a los entornos de trabajo.

He intentado realizar lo siguiente con politicas IAM en el grupo de usuarios pero no ha funcionado.

Este es el JSON de la política.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCodeCommitActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreatePRFromDev",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "codecommit:CreatePullRequest",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": "refs/heads/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

He editado la política de varias formas y de ninguna forma me ha funcionado, es como si no funcionara el **condition** porque en unas ediciones no funcionaba y en otras denegaba permiso a todo.

Si retiro el IfExists de StringEqualsIfExists no funciona, si pongo el condition **"NULL"** tampoco me funciona, en teoria con eso ya deberia funcionar pero nada, que me falta o que otra forma puedo hacer para conseguir estos bloqueos.

El PR automatico esta en un ROL asi que la politica no le afecta, necesito que sea al crear el PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awscodecommit.html) de AWS, la acción `codecommit:CreatePullRequest` no tiene condiciones, luego el `Condition` no se va a evaluar nunca.

Con roles no vas a conseguir tu propósito. En cualquier caso no parece que sea posible aplicar tu configuración por otros métodos.

Lo siento.

Comment: Contacte al soporte de AWS y efectivamente tienes razón, todavía no se puede.